# Finding Limits, will limits be defined in question?

Tags: limits

How do you know which limits to take  x tends to 0 or x tends to infinity for 
(3-2x)/(x+2) and does it matter

Comment: Do you mean "What's the difference between $\lim_{x\to 0}$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}$, and when do we use each of them?" or is your question something else?

Comment: I wanted to know if it had to be one or the other or it depends on a situation like the question will define it so you do that

Comment: Usually it's obious from the problem which limit you're supposed to take. If not, then, well, you should choose the one which makes the most sense.

Comment: Hi Arthur, could you answer "What's the difference between limx→0 and limx→∞, and when do we use each of them?", maybe that will help my understanding better

Comment: You can use for example $x \rightarrow \infty$ limit to find out if the $f$ has horizontal asymptote at $\infty$. If the $\lim f(x) = a$ where $a$ is some number different than infinity, then the function has horizontal asymptote equal to $y = a$ at $\infty$. On the other hand for example you can calculate $x \rightarrow 0$ limit to find out if the curve has a vertical asymptote at $x$. You can also use it to find out if $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$. This is a huge generalization from my side, but you get the idea. Do some reading.

Comment: Thanks Weno starting to make sense, will do some more reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $x$ tends to zero, you can plug in $x=0$.
If $x$ tends to infinity, you can write
$$\frac {x\left(\frac{3}{x}-2\right)}{x\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)}$$

Comment: x tends to 0 will give 3/2 while x tends to infinity will give -2, so I wanted clarity on which best to pick